# nodejs watch mocha before/each

Tags: node.js, filesystems, mocha.js

I've started to write my own wrapper around fs.watch (not satisfied with watchify and chokidar) and so far everything works as expected.

But here's where things start to get funny: In my mocha unit test I'm setting up a testfolder by

1. deleting it with rimraf
2. recreating it with `fs.mkdir`

in a `before` hook. Then in the test I create a new file inside the testfolder which emits a `rename` event, just as expected, and the test succeeds.

Now I wanted to write several tests so I changed `before` to `beforeEach` and ran it again but now the event emitted is `change`???
Why does changing a mocha-hook alter the filesystem behaviour?

**UPDATE 1 - GIST LINK**
https://gist.github.com/hesxenon/a762a3fce3aa2dac1b1cb95ae1f547b2

**UPDATE 2 - Closing**
Since this question isn't getting any attention anymore and I've rewritten everything anyway I'd only be interested in an answer for academic purposes.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @LarryTurtis in theory, yes. But since I have no idea where I've gone wrong I'd have to share everything, so I'll just provide a gist link with the two files index.ts and test.ts